# Google map search by address

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-maps, dom

how can I search by location(address).

I want to pass the location to my map. Now I have added lat, long.
Or is there a quick way to find out the lat and long with javascript?

```
 var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000), Here I want to just add the location for example Dublin, Ireland
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pc7Uu/346

Thanks for your help.

Best

Comment: Why don't you look at the docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called Geocoding, it is actually very easy to use, read the [The Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?csw=1)  to get started, since you are using JavaScript you don't need an API_KEY so you can actually convert addresses to lat/lng values with requests like this:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway,%20Mountain%20View,%20CA)

You will get a JSON with the coordinates inside the "location" key, like this:

```
...
"location" : {
    "lat" : 37.4220352,
    "lng" : -122.0841244
},
...
```

There are changes from V2 to V3 (recommended). Here are both documentations in case you want use an specific version:

V3 API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

V2 API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding

If you want autocomplete functionality and/or site name to lat/lng coordinates, check the [Place Autocomplete Hotel Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch) example.

Comment: How can I access to the json objects? I tried $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway,%20Mountain%20View,%20CA', function(data){
console.log('aasdfasfasfsdf' + data.geometry);
});

Answer (score 0):

I think your present code won't do what you are trying to do.

First, here's what the code needs to do, in plain English. I will explain each part later.

**1. Send a request to the Google Geocoding API** : This request will include the address you are trying to find lat&lng for. You will receive a response in the form of JSON, which you will parse to get the information you need.

**2. Save the information (latitude and longitude) in a variable**

**3. Create a map, and use the lat&lng you found above as its center.**

Okay, now here are the sources for the code. Don't worry, these code samples are very straightforward and you will easily understand what to do.

1. How to send the 'GET' request:

   ```
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (request.readyState === 4) {
           if (request.status === 200) {
               document.body.className = 'ok';
           } else {
               document.body.className = 'error';
           }
       }
   };
   request.open("GET", url , true);
   request.send(null);
   ```

The http request for geocoding:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingRequests

2. Here is what the code will look like: (example)

   ```
   var json = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+"ADD ADDRESS HERE"&key=YOUR_API_KEY;
   var object = JSON.parse(json);
   ```
3. Then you can extract the lat&lng from this object.
4. After that, create a map using: (link) www.developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

(Use the latitude and longitude you extracted above as the 'center' of the google map you will create)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?csw=1) is intended for that purpose, the below example shows how to set map center based on the provided address:

```js
//Data
var cities = [
    {
        city : 'Toronto',
        desc : 'This is the best city in the world!',
        lat : 43.7000,
        long : -79.4000
    },
    {
        city : 'New York',
        desc : 'This city is aiiiiite!',
        lat : 40.6700,
        long : -73.9400
    },
    {
        city : 'Chicago',
        desc : 'This is the second best city in the world!',
        lat : 41.8819,
        long : -87.6278
    },
    {
        city : 'Los Angeles',
        desc : 'This city is live!',
        lat : 34.0500,
        long : -118.2500
    },
    {
        city : 'Las Vegas',
        desc : 'Sin City...\'nuff said!',
        lat : 36.0800,
        long : -115.1522
    }
];

//Angular App Module and Controller
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope) {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        //center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    


    var setMapCenterByAddress = function(map,address) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        if (geocoder) {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                         map: map,
                         position: results[0].geometry.location,
                         title: address
                    });
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    setMapCenterByAddress($scope.map,'Dublin, Ireland');

});
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>
<style>
#map {
    height:420px;
    width:600px;
}
</style>
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin it is very simple:

https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

alternative free service of geo location to coordinates you can use openstreet map, you can combine this with [jquery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/